# sFTP on Azure, VM is the way?

Tags: azure

I've to allow users to upload files with sFTP, I've done some test using a virtual machine that writes to a blob storage and it seems to work quite well. I was wondering if it is the best approach (maybe I can consider to create a second VM and balance it for fault tolerance) or can I have something in Azure App Service so I don't have to allocate a virtual machine?

Thanks

Comment: what client protocols are you allowed to use?  Does it have to be SFTP?

Comment: yes it has to be secure ftp

Comment: If you have to use SFTP, then VMs are probably the way to go.

Comment: See my answer to related question here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747319/sftp-ftp-service-on-azure)

Answer (score 2):

**Azure VM** is the right solution for you.

FYI, Azure App Service provides support for **FTPS = FTP + SSL**  and not SFTP

Comment: Right, but the FTPS support is for deploying code, it is not consumer side (which is HTTP/HTTPS only).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What are you going to use SFTP for?