# SFTP/FTP Service on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

We are using Azure WebApps and we have this requirement: An external automated client will be connecting to us a few times a day through FTP and drop a small size file < 1KB, we need to act on the data and update our DB accordingly.

Unfortunately, we have no control on the external client and the client will need to communicate via FTP. To me this should have been a RESTful call.

I am fine with setting a Windows Server with IIS as a VM to act as an FTP server or on Ubuntu, but that means a maintenance of a VM for this small requirement.

Are you aware of any Azure specific service that helps in this situation?

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579355/can-we-set-up-a-ftp-site-using-azure-web-app

Comment: @JeremyLattimore I have seen this, but they are saying the VM is the only option and this was a year ago. I wanted to see if this has changed.

Comment: This might be of help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp

But I think it's limited to deployment - and I don't imagine you would want to receive this file as a 're-deploy'.